# MacPorts: time stamp of lastest revision to a given port

Tags: macports

The time of latest revision to a port is a pretty reliable criterion for deciding whether a port is dormant/abandoned or not.

In the web interface of MacPorts, we can see when the port is last updated, e.g., the latest revision of the [Portfile](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/perl/p5-image-exiftool/Portfile) of `p5-image-exiftool` is labelled as 7 weeks ago as of 05/03/2014.

However, in the command line, I've tried virtually all options for `port info` without luck of getting the time stamp:

```
Usage: info --category --categories --depends_fetch --depends_extract
            --depends_build --depends_lib --depends_run --depends --description
            --epoch --fullname --heading --homepage --index --license --line
            --long_description --maintainer --maintainers --name --platform
            --platforms --portdir --pretty --replaced_by --revision --subports
            --variant --variants --version
```

Therefore, I'm wondering if it is possible at all to extract the time stamp? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to extract the information from `port info`, because it would need the repository history to determine the info, and since MacPorts (currently) uses SVN and doesn't sync a SVN working copy of the ports tree to users, the info is only available on the server. Now, you could probably write a little script that parses the output of `port file $portname` and fetches the modification date from svn.macports.org, but I think `/usr/bin/stat -f %Sm $(port file $portname)` would probably work well for your specific need of finding the date of the last change.

Comment: Thanks, this not only answers my question, but also teaches me something I didn't know about — MacPorts operates on SVN. Though I'm not sure what the magical `/usr/bin/stat -f %Sm $(port file $portname)` is doing, it works.

Comment: `/usr/bin/stat` prints information on files. By passing `-f %Sm` you instruct it to print the modification date (`m`) in human-readable form (`S`). `$(port file $portname)` simply returns the path to the Portfile of the given port. You could also try experimenting with `$(port dir $portname)` instead of `$(port file $portname)` to get the modification date of the port's directory, since some files in the directory might have been updated after the Portfile.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Actually I've figured it out by reading the man page of `stat`, which I was too lazy to read when I posted the last comment.